# Не получается в методе МАХ вывести максимум. С созданием массива вроде все в порядке

Tags: java, массивы

Код должен создавать и набивать массив числами с клавиатуры в методе `initializeArray`. Метод `max` должен получать максимум из массива метода `initializeArray` и возвращать этот максимум в метод `main`. Загвоздка в методе `max`. Он не выполняет то что должен. Не возвращает максимум в метод `main`:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Solution5 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int[] array = initializeArray();
    int max = max(array);
    System.out.println(max);
}
public static int[] initializeArray() throws IOException {
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(System.in));
  int[]array = new int[20];
  for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array[i] = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
  }
    return null;
}
public static int max(int[] array) {

  for(int j = 0; j > array.length; j++) {
    if(array[j] > max(array)) {
      max(array) = array[j];
        }
      }
  return 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: Вопрос-то в чём?

Comment: Поправил описание. Спасибо что задали вопрос))

Comment: Так отредактируйте свой вопрос и добавте метку "массивы".

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста что должен делать этот код и что он делает.

Comment: @default locale Код должен создавать и набивать массив числами с клавиатуры в методе initializeArray. Метод max должен получать максимум из массива метода initializeArray и возвращать этот максимум в метод main. Загвоздка в методе MAX. Он не выполняет то что должен. Не возвращает максимум в метод main

Comment: @AlexeyVL Внес описание в вопрос. Рад что Вы получили ответ. В следующий раз если код не компилируется, приводите ошибки компиляции, чтобы сразу было видно где проблема.

Comment: @default locale Спасибо! Да, буду в следующий раз подробнее описывать проблему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот ваш готовый код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int[] array = initializeArray();
    int max = max(array);
    System.out.println(max);
}
public static int[] initializeArray() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new
            InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int[]array = new int[20];
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    }
    return array;
}
public static int max(int[] array) {
    int maximum = array[0];
    for(int j = 1; j < array.length; j++) {
        if(array[j] > maximum) {
            maximum = array[j];
        }
    }
    return maximum;
}
```

1. Ошибка в операторе **return** в методе **initializeArray()**.
2. Метод **max** переработан с минимумом исправлений. Без добавления одной переменной  никак.
3. Обратите внимание, в цикле **for** знак **>** заменен на **<**.

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь понял этот код благодаря вам! Вернее, почти понял. Буду разбираться.

Comment: Не за что. Я тоже только учусь. И совет: выберите книгу по Java Хортсманна или Шилдта, так в разы быстрее обучитесь.

Comment: Спасибо за совет! Примусь за изучение этой книги.

Comment: @Belladon В вашем коде ошибка. Если массив пустой, метод `max()` выбросит исключение и программа упадёт. Так же проще использовать цикл for-each и не возиться с индексами. Посмотрите мой вариант ответа.

Comment: Да, Ростислав, вы абсолютно правы. Я бы и сам так делал. А свой ответ я писал исходя из комментария вопрошающего под вашим ответом и максимально приближенно к его коду. Так же я не считаю отсутствие условия на заполненность массива ошибкой. Это упрощение, как и то, что в методе initializeArray() надо бы добавить конструкцию try {} catch, на случай если пользователь введет букву вместо цифры.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static Integer max(int[] array) {
    Integer maxNum = null;
    for (int num : array) {
        if (maxNum == null || num > maxNum) {
            maxNum = num;
        }
    }
    return maxNum;
}
```

Comment: Сорри, а без MIN_VALUE можно сделать же, как раз такое решение желательно.

Comment: @AlexeyVL, напишите int maxNum = array[0];

Comment: Ребят, спасибо за помощь но я не вставлю maxNum и num в свой код. У меня там другие имена. Еще больше запутаюсь. Я вообще зеленый в этом деле пока что.

Comment: @AlexeyVL я изменил код, теперь там нет `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, так же он корректно работает с пустым массивом. Имена локальных переменных можно изменить на свой вкус.

Comment: Не выводит максимум на экран. Надо чтобы в метод main возвращались значения.

Comment: Это же не вся программа, а лишь метод `max()`. Вызовите его из `main()` и возвращённое значение распечатайте на экран. Вы уже делаете это в вашем исходном коде.

Comment: Ростислав, да, ваш код по идее работающий. Просто надо было еще в методе initializeArray поправить return, наверно из за этого не работало. - как вариант. Может я ошибаюсь.

Comment: @AlexeyVL вы же сами написали, что: "с созданием массива вроде всё в порядке", поэтому я на `initializeArray()` даже не посмотрел.

Comment: Это моя вина, return не учел.